# Return values differ depending on vector size

Tags: matlab

I noticed that for example the `log(x)` function returns slightly different values when called with vectors of different sizes in MATLAB.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
x1 = 0.1:0.1:1;
x2 = 0.1:0.1:1.1;

y1 = log(x1);
y2 = log(x2);

d = y1 - y2(1:length(x1));

d(7)
```

Executing returns:

```
>> ans = 
  -1.6653e-16
```

The behaviour seems to start when the vector becomes greater than 10 entries.

Although the difference is very small, when being scaled by a lot of operations using large vectors, the errors became big enough to notice.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences exist in `x1` and `x2` and those errors are propagated and potentially accentuated by `log`.

```
max(abs(x1 - x2(1:numel(x1))))
% 1.1102e-16
```

This is due to the inability of floating point number to represent your data *exactly*. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I did not expect that the output of the colon operator differs for these sequences.

Comment: Is this a recent “development” in Matlab? I remember a few years ago trying to track down the differences between two Matlab functions that ought to have been producing bit-exact results and checking to make sure that there was no difference between the overlapping intervals of `[start : step : stop1]` and `[start : step : stop2]`. This seems like a catastrophic bug. Numpy, for example, does it “right”: `np.all(np.arange(0.1,1.0, 0.1) == np.arange(0.1, 1.1, 0.1)[:9])` returns `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Suever’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530574/500207), this is because for unfathomable reasons, Matlab’s colon operator `[start : step : stop]` with floating-point `step` produces non-bit-exact results even when `start` and `step` are the same, and only `stop` is different.

**This is wrong**, although it’s not unknown: in a [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/23/a-glimpse-into-floating-point-accuracy/) from 2006 (search for “Typical MATLAB Pitfall”), Loren notes that [`:` colon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator can suffer from floating-point accuracy issues.

**Numpy/Python** does it right:

```
import numpy as np
np.all(np.arange(0.1,1.0+1e-4, 0.1) == np.arange(0.1, 1.1+1e-4, 0.1)[:-1]) # => True
```

(`np.arange(start, stop, step)` doesn’t include `stop` so I use `stop+1e-4` above.)

**Julia** does it right too:

```
all(collect(0.1 : 0.1 : 1) .== collect(0.1 : 0.1 : 1.1)[1:10]) # => true
```

**Alternative.** Here’s a straightforward guess as to what Numpy’s `arange` is doing, in Matlab:

```
function y = arange(start, stop, step)
%ARANGE An alternative to Matlab's colon operator
%
%  The API for this function follows Numpy's arange [1].
%
%  ARANGE(START, STOP, STEP) produces evenly-spaced values within the half-open
%  interval [START, STOP). The resulting vector has CEIL((STOP - START) / STEP)
%  elements and is roughly equivalent to (START : STEP : STOP - STEP / 2), but
%  may differ from this COLON-based version due to numerical differences.
%
%  ARANGE(START, STOP) assumes STEP of 1.0.
%
%  [1] http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

if nargin < 3 || isempty(step)
  step = 1.0;
end
len = ceil((stop - start) / step);
y = start + (0 : len - 1) * step;
```

This function tries to keep things exact until the last possible moment, when it applies the scaling by `step` and shifting by `start`. With this, your original two vectors are bit-exact over their shared interval:

```
y1 = arange(0.1, 1.0 + 1e-4, 0.1);
y2 = arange(0.1, 1.1 + 1e-4, 0.1);
all(y2(1:numel(y1)) == y1) % => 1
```

And therefore all downstream operations like `log` are also bit-exact.

I will investigate whether this *bug* in Matlab is causing any problems in our internal code and check if we should enforce using `linspace` (which I believe, but have not checked, does not suffer as much from accuracy issues) or something like `arange` above instead of `:` for floating-point steps. (`arange` also can be tricky because, as the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) note, depending on `(stop-start)/step`, you may get a vector whose last element is greater than `stop` sometimes—those same docs also recommend using `linspace` with non-unit steps.)

Comment: `linspace` *also* has issues, just not as severe.